# Can not able to create directory in host server

Tags: php, host, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder in server. I wrote the following code

```
function CreateErrorLog($IntegrationId, $errorStr){

    if (!is_dir(PUBLIC_PATH.'/errors/'.$IntegrationId)) {

        echo 'not present<br/><br/>';
        try{
                mkdir(PUBLIC_PATH.'/errors/'.$IntegrationId, 0777);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo '<br/><br/> exception----'.$e.'<br/><br/>';
            print_r($e);
        }

    }else{
        echo 'present<br/><br/>';

    }
}
```

I am getting output "not present" but I can`t see the directory created in the name of $IntegrationId under "errors" folder.
this is working in localhost. After moving to remote server I am getting the problem. What is the problem?

Comment: Please check the permission of `errors` folder in server

Comment: Thanks. errors folders has permission 777 in server

Comment: Sorry. I added 777 permission from filezilla but it is not executing properly. It is giving error "500 'SITE CHMOD 777 errors': command not understood"

Comment: Hi, I came to know from filezilla forum that chmode does not supported by windows server. it has to be unix/linux server http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4659

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be `errors` folder might not be having `write` permission in server

If no permission, it will not through any exception.

Put the mkdir in if() condition. So you will understand from the return value.

And put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your path permission is writable.If this fine,you must mention absolute path   instead of PUBLIC_PATH.you can get absolute path create a php file using function 'echo getcwd()'.This will show you absolute path.This choose on instead of PUBLIC_PATH.